# My domain name doesn't get resolved. How come?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name

We recently created a website called http://www.laundryday.be/ but the domain name suddenly doesn't get resolved anymore on the other hand the IP address 77.73.98.252 does work correctly.

What could be the problem for this and more importantly what's the solution?

We do not maintain the server ourselves, it's another company that does it for us.

We do have access to the server trough ssh, is it possible to fix it this way or is this a no go for sure?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is no A (address) record for the domain. You need to create one to map laundryday.be to 77.73.98.252. If the site is hosted elsewhere, contact the provider and see if they offer DNS services. Make sure your domain is pointing to a valid nameserver.

If you need to create your own A records, you can do this with a free DNS provider like [ZoneEdit](http://zoneedit.com/). If you are unsure of what is going on, you can use the tools at [network-tools.com](http://network-tools.com/) to give you a clearer picture.

Comment: OK, everything seems to be okay now, very strange. Probably an error at the hosting company or some sort

Answer (score 2):

One of your DNS servers is down **(77.73.98.229)**.  You (and some of your visitors) are going to be seeing intermittent problems until this gets fixed.